# Scroll to and select final row in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, scroll, wpftoolkit

How do I make a WPF Toolkit DataGrid scroll to and select the bottom row without using the code behind?

For context, when the user wants to add a new row to the table I don't want them to have to scroll through hundreds of rows to get to the bottom.

Comment: If you don't want to use any code behind, when do you want the `DataGrid` to Scroll to the bottom? Do you raise a specific event?

Comment: I'll decide that in the view model. I'm more interested in the how than the when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DataGrid.ScrollIntoView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673083%28VS.95%29.aspx) method

Check the below links

[WPF DataGrid - How to stay focused on the bottom of the DataGrid as new rows are added?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296927/217880)

[How to autoscroll on WPF datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1027051/217880)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f651812c-95db-436e-a98e-d5eeccb779e5/

Answer (score -1):

This will scroll/focus to the bottom of the grid

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount-1;
```